# Http Cache-Control Clashes with Multiple Browser Tabs/Sessions

Tags: node.js, angular, http, hapi.js, http-caching

I am using Angular 5, with a Hapi NodeJs backend. When I send the "cache-control: private, max-age=3600" header in the http response the response is cached correctly. The problem is that when I make the exact same request in a different tab and with connections to different database the data cached in the browser tab 1 is shared with browser tab 2 when it make the same request. Is there a way for the cache to only be used per application instance using the cache-control header?

- Same Webapp in Browser Tab 1. Same Domain.

  - Database 1
- Same Webapp in Browser Tab 2. Same Domain.

  - Database 2

Comment: Can you describe in more details what kind of a request is it? Why both resources stored in different databases have same URI?

Comment: My Webapp is supposed to be deployed in various facilities all with their own db. Yet it is not uncommon for the user to work in more that one db at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User agent needs to somehow differentiate these cache entries. Probably your best option is to adjust a cache entry key (add subdomain, path or query parameter that identifies a database to a URI).

You can also use custom HTTP header (such as `X-Database`), in pair with `Vary` HTTP header but in this case user agent may store only single response at a time because it is still uses URI as cache key and `Vary` HTTP header for response validation only. Relevant excerpt from [The State of Browser Caching, Revisited](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching) article by Mark Nottingham:

> The one hiccup I saw was that **all tested browser caches would only store one variant at a time;** i.e., if your responses contain `Vary: Foo` and you get two requests, the first with `Foo: 1` and the second with `Foo: 2`, the second response will evict the first from cache.
>
> Whether that’s a problem depends on how you use `Vary`; if you want to reuse cached responses with old values, it might reduce efficiency. However, that doesn’t seem like a common use case;

For more information check [RFC 7234 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234),  and [Understanding The Vary Header](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/understanding-vary-header/) article by Andrew Betts